# Enabling to RRAS, gives ICS error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rras

When I want to enable RRAS on Windows Server 2008 R2 (for VPN connection), I take this error. *"ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) is currently enabled on , to configure RRAS, disable ICS and try again."* I can't find ICS settings. How can I fix it?

Comment: Stop and disable the Internet Connection Sharing service and try again.

Comment: @joeqwerty I disabled in services, but still there is problem. Is there any other location that I must disable?